# Скопировать значение массива, а не ссылку на него

Tags: javascript, массивы

Здравствуйте! Скажите, а как можно скопировать в JavaScript массив так, чтобы, при изменении копии, оригинал не менялся? Например:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
b = clone(a)
b[0] = 10
a[0] == 0 // => true
```

Можно ли реализовать такой метод `clone`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```js
var a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
var b = a.slice(0);


b[0] = 10;
console.log('a: ' + a);
console.log('b: ' + b);
```

[slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) - возвращает поверхностную копию части массива в новый объект массива.

В данном случае с начала и до конца

---

Технически `slice` - наибыстрый путь, **ОДНАКО** это будет даже еще быстрее если добавить `0` - как начало "отрезания"

```
myArray.slice(0);
```

быстрее, чем

```
myArray.slice();
```

....так говорят языки %)

Comment: Скажите, а как сделать так:

    a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
    change(a)

     a == [1, 2] // => true

     a = [3, 2, 1]
     b = какой_то_метод(a)
     change(b)
     b == [2, 1] // => true
     a == [3, 2, 1] // => true

Comment: Действительно [быстрее](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/550998/178988) :)

Answer (score 7):

## Замер производительности

В хроме `slice(0)` действительно немного быстрее, чем просто `slice()` и в 2 раза быстрее, чем `concat`. А вот `Array.from` даже `concat`у проигрывает в 10 раз - 3 секунды на миллион итераций о_О.

А вот Edge так не считает - там `concat` самый быстрый. А `Array.from` по-прежнему в 10 (с хвостиком) раз медленнее `concat`а - 1.4 секунды.

При запуске сниппета браузер повиснет на несколько секунд - это нормально.

```js
function test(f) {
  var a = [0, 1, 2, 3];
  var t = performance.now();
  f(a);
  t = performance.now() - t;
  console.log((""+f).match(/var b = .*$/m)[0] + " // " + t.toFixed(3) + " ms");
}

test(function testSlice(a) {
  for (var q=0; q<1000000; ++q) {
    var b = a.slice();
  }
});

test(function testSlice0(a) {
  for (var q=0; q<1000000; ++q) {
    var b = a.slice(0);
  }
});

test(function testConcat(a) {
  for (var q=0; q<1000000; ++q) {
    var b = [].concat(a);
  }
});

test(function testFrom(a) {
  for (var q=0; q<1000000; ++q) {
    var b = Array.from(a);
  }
});

test(function testAssign(a) { // Так делать не надо, просто для сравнения
  for (var q=0; q<1000000; ++q) {
    var b = Object.assign([], a);
  }
});

test(function testDesruct(a) {
  for (var q=0; q<1000000; ++q) {
    var b = [...a];
  }
});
```

Comment: Yandex 51.0.2704.3342 x32: 149 / 145 / 294 / 2949 / 2342.

Comment: Edge 38.14393.0.0, Microsoft EdgeHTML 14.14393: 156 / 150 / 120 / 1321 / 929

Comment: Раз уж я попенял в соседнем ответе про микробенчмарки, то попеняю и тут. Браузерные оптимизации js движка - они бывают очень хитрые, и такие микробенчмарки могут совершенно спокойно врать про реальную производительность операций.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, добавил свежий тест. Кстати, у меня slice без нолика ускорился и стал быстрее))) Как сделать, чтобы в ES5 работало?

Comment: еще раз, начнем с того что Вы меряете операцию без использования результата (первое правило бенчмарков вообще-то), для es6 конструкций это вообще "бенчмарк полифилла который подключается в песочницу", ну то есть какие-то цифры которые говорят очень мало о чем.

Comment: В общем я призываю убрать из ответа всякие выводы или сильно задуматься над усовершенствованием механизма измерения

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, какого ещё полифила? Babel в сниппете отключен, всё отправляется в браузер как есть. И в том ответе тоже - я это сразу проверил.

Comment: FF 50.1.0: 149 / 149 / 149 / 900 / 1927 / 435.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, если ты считаешь, что в замере что-то неправильно, предложи, как замерить правильно. Ну или хотя бы покажи, в каком именно месте неправильно. В данный момент я не вижу причин так считать.

Answer (score 6):

```
var oldArray = [0, 1, 2, 3];
var newArray = oldArray.slice();
```

Answer (score 6):

```js
var a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
var b = [].concat(a)

b[0] = 10

console.log(a + '\n' + b)
```

Answer (score 3):

Способ, который работает и в случае, когда в массиве есть массивы или объекты:

```js
var a = [[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,2,1]]
var b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a))
b[0][0]=5
console.log(a)
console.log(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let myArr = [1, 2, 3];
let myArr2 = myArr.map(el => el);
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]