# При изменении одного массива меняется другой

Tags: javascript, массивы, dom

Пишу код для нахождения полиндромов в строке, но проблема в том, что, когда я  присвоил значения одного массива другому, и меняю значения второго массива, первый массив тоже  меняется, хотя в цикле я его не указывал вообще. Как от этого  избавиться и почему  это происходит?

```
btn.onclick = function(){
    let str=document.querySelector('.str');
    str=[...str.value].reverse();//переворачиваю строку
    let count_str=[], i, j, val,len;
    count_str=str;
    len=count_str.length-1;
    for(i=0;i<=len;i++){
        val=count_str[0];
        count_str[i]=count_str[len];
        count_str[len]=val;
    }
    alert(str);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/object-copy

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Основы JavaScript, копия объектов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511436/%d0%9e%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b-javascript-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Массив в *Javascript* - это объект и он передаётся по ссылке, а не по значению Для корректного поверхностного копирования можно использовать `slice`:

```
count_str = str.slice(0);
```

Ещё больше вариантов тут:

**[Скопировать значение массива, а не ссылку на него](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/550976/191482)**